# Touchmove into Mousemove

Tags: javascript, css

How do I get touchmove recognised as mousemove, I want to use the script below which works on pc but not mobile or tablets. Is there a way to recognise touchmove as mousemove?

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
        $('#try').css({
           left:  e.pageX -300,
            top:   e.pageY -145
        });
    });

      </script>
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to just register a `touchmove` listener with a common callback?

Comment: would I do somethings like on.touchmove (function(e){mousemove})??

Comment: Just use `touchmove` event, more you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove
It generate each time the finger move on the touch screen.

Comment: Thanks this works but only on touchdown. The div isn't following moves just when I press once

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the common code in a separate function, like this:

```
function onMouseMove(x, y) {
    $('#try').css({
        left:  x -300,
        top:   y -145
    });
}
```

Then register event listeners for both `mousemove` and `touchmove` that forward the coordinates to your common function:

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    onMouseMove(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(e){
    var touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    onMouseMove(touch.pageX, touch.pageY);
});
```